# Scripting help for copying new items added to a set of directories

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a set of folders which have new files being added to them regularly, but I have to process those files as they come in. This can be a time consuming process to dig into each folder one by one. I need to figure out how to write a script that will filter out the new files, and copy them into a new directory.

So far I have figured out how to use the Get-ChildItem -Path -Recurse command in powershell to list the new items in the corresponding folders as shown in the third script on [this Microsoft page.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-files-and-folders?view=powershell-7.2)

So I can see the new files in their folders. How do I copy those items to the destination folder while replicating their original folder structure? I want to be able to recreate the original folders  so that I can just overwrite the originals with the edited versions later.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered robocopy, and was able to use it to solve my problem. The /maxage:x option was perfect for my needs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).